# Rspec expect( ) vs expect { }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Hi I am new to rspec and was trying to figure out what is the difference between passing a block to expect{ } and just using expect( )

Here is a trivial example

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe "Test",type: :model do
 it "testing count" do
   arr=[1,2,3]
   expect{arr<<1}.to change{arr.count}.by(1)
 end
end
```

This runs fine but when I do this instead

```
    require "rails_helper"
    RSpec.describe "Test",type: :model do
      it "testing count" do
        arr=[1,2,3]
        expect(arr<<1).to change{arr.count}.by(1)
      end
    end
```

It throws an error

```
Failures:

  1) Test testing count
     Failure/Error: expect(arr<<1).to change{arr.count}.by(1)
       expected `arr.count` to have changed by 1, but was not given a block
     # ./spec/models/test_spec.rb:6:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

And even when I don't use a block with change it gives me an error

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe "Test",type: :model do
  it "testing count" do
    arr=[1,2,3]
    expect{arr<<1}.to change(arr.count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Failures:

```
  1) Test testing count
     Failure/Error: expect{arr<<1}.to change(arr.count).by(1)
     
     ArgumentError:
       `change` requires either an object and message (`change(obj, :msg)`) or a block (`change { }`). You passed an object but no message.
```

Can someone explain why is it happening??

Comment: From a Ruby evaluation point: writing `method(expression)` will evaluate the expression right away and only once. Passing a block, i.e. `method { expression }` will defer evaluation of the expression until the block is actually called. It also allows the block to be called more than once. Having `expect { ... }.to change { ... }` allows RSpec to retrieve the "before state" by calling the change block, then run the expect block and finally retrieve the "after state" by calling the change block again.

Comment: So what this means is that the change block calls the expect block to be executed?

Comment: No, the blocks don't executed one another. RSpec executes them. The point I was trying to make is that using blocks allows RSpecs to execute the expressions you pass inside these blocks programmatically. Without blocks, `expect(arr<<1).to change(arr.count).by(1)` is equivalent to `expect([1,2,3,1]).to change(4).by(1)` – apparently that can't possibly work. With blocks, it's up to RSpec to execute the expressions `arr<<1` and `arr.count`, i.e. it can run `arr.count`, then execute `arr<1` and afterwards run `arr.count` again and finally check whether the result changed by 1.

Comment: Ok thank you now it's a lot clearer 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `expect(...)` syntax is used to expect that the *return value* of the statement in the parentheses matches a certain condition, like:

```
expect(result).to eq(3)
expect(list).not_to be_empty
expect(string).to match(/regexp/)
expect(1..10).to cover(3)
```

The `expect { ... }` runs the block and doesn't really care about the return value of the block, but instead about the *side-effects* of running the code in the block. Like that another value changes by running the block or that an exception is raised.

```
expect { api_request }.to raise_error(NotFoundError)
expect { object.action }.to change(object, :value).from(old).to(new)
expect { actual }.to output("some output").to_stdout
```

Find more [examples in the RSpec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-11/docs/built-in-matchers)

In your example

```
expect { array << 1 }.to change { array.count }.by(1)
```

because a *side-effect* of pushing a value into an array is that the count of elements in the array changes. But

```
expect(array << 1).to change { arr.count }.by(1)
```

does not work, because the *return value* of `expect(array << 1)` is `[1, 2, 3, 1]` and this syntax does not support the `change` matcher.